# Create li list with ids from 'for each' function and then use onclick dynamically on the newly created items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function below that gets me all the available pages (name.displayname) in my embedded report, along with their ids (page.name) and puts them into a html list

```
$("#showreports").click(async function() {


  let pages = await report.getPages();
  ul = document.createElement('ul');
  pages.forEach(function(page) {

   document.getElementById("reportlist").innerHTML += '<li id=' + page.name +'>' + page.displayName + '</li>';
});

});
```

[image]

I have a separate function that can reload the active report page on click using a static ID

(ID is in the format "ReportSectionxxxxxxxxxxxx")

```
$("#report1").click(function() {
  report.setPage("ReportSection80609a506b587e04c723");
  //Log.logText("Page was set to: ReportSectiona271643cba2213c935be");
});

$("#report2").click(function() {
  report.setPage("ReportSection6fc0357887900a6c4345");
  //Log.logText("Page was set to: ReportSectiona271643cba2213c935be");
})
```

Ideally what I want is to be able to use the newly created list to act as a navigation for updating the active page.  Where I can click on one of the pages in the list and it will use report.setPage

Maybe something like:

```
$("#reportlist").click(function() {
      report.setPage(li);
      
    })
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: All you have really provided is a partial and not very well detailed goal. You really haven't identified what your specific problem is in achieving your goal. Please also provide a [mcve] along with the updated details

Comment: What you are likely looking for is ***event delegation*** ... `$("#reportlist").on('click', 'li', function(){// this is element that was clicked })`